# JQuery datatable object datasource not working

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am trying to create a JQuery datatable with a js generated datasource.

I have this object:

```
 [
  {
    "a": -817,
    "b": null,
    "c": "Default",
    "total": -817
  },
  {
    "a": -21,
    "b": 12,
    "c": "Default",
    "total": -897
  }
]
```

And this datatable:

```
table1.DataTable({
    "ajax":  dataSource,
    "columns": [
        {
            "className": 'details-control',
            "orderable": false,
            "data": null,
            "defaultContent": ''
        },
        {
            "orderable": true,
            "data": "a",
            "defaultContent": ''
        },
        {
            "orderable": true,
            "data": "b",
            "defaultContent": ''
        },
        {
            "orderable": true,
            "data": "c",
            "defaultContent": ''
        },
        {
            "orderable": true,
            "data": "total",
            "defaultContent": ''
        }
    ],
    "paging": false,
    "bInfo": false,
    "bFilter": false,
    "order": [
        [1, "asc"]
    ]
)};
```

I tried manipulating datasource like this:

- JSON.stringify(datasource)
- add a field before the the array (  {data : datasource} ) and change ajax scection to:  "ajax": { "url":datasource, "dataSrc":"data"}   with or without stringihfy

nothing seems to work.

Help please

Regards, Ido

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your data object is not in correct format of datatables, it should look like this:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": [
        "Nixon",
        "Tiger"
      ],
      "hr": [
        "System Architect",
        "$320,800",
        "2011/04/25"
      ],
      "office": "Edinburgh",
      "extn": "5421"
    }]
  }
```

There is a data objects that wraps it all.

Take a look at this [Fiddle](https://plnkr.co/edit/bfCmHmpZchsQcHHLr6cq?p=preview) and the way I access to the data.

Comment: Thanks, but it is almost fixed the problem. 
I changed your fiddle to simulate my problem:
https://plnkr.co/edit/EmjE11nnx8amkBTiBK2t?p=preview

I have to generate the data inline (it is a part of an object).

Comment: Try this: 
https://plnkr.co/edit/YZxiSjslpSOApypi2GUQ?p=preview

Comment: Yes... I tried to avoid manipulating the objects and create this array of values.  If there is no other option I will do so. Thanks.

Comment: Say hello to Ilan Rosen.